# How can I force Outlook 2013 to send an email stuck in outbox?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2013

I've got an email that's stuck in outbox because when it was sent there was no internet connection. Now this message is stuck in the outbox. I know I can delete the email and send it again, copy/paste the contents and send it now, but my problem is the date it was sent is important.

It is some work I did, and I send it in time for a deadline. I fulfill the task in time, but because I didn't notice the problem, now if I just forward or re send the message, it will be sent with today's date and that's a problem.

How can I force Outlook to send my message at outbox keeping the date it was first sent?

If I need to install a plugin or something to accomplish this, I'll do it.
THANKS!